# Get multiple posts by multiple slugs

Tags: wordpress

I have an array with multiple slugs (post names) and I want to get all posts where the slug is in the array.

I use Event Organsier and want to get all events these slugs. I haven't worked with WordPress for a couple of years so I need some help.

```
$events = eo_get_events(array(
 'numberposts'=>5,
 'event_start_after'=> $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day,
 'event_end_before'=> $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day,
 'showpastevents'=>false,//Will be deprecated, but set it to true to play it safe.
 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array('slug-example-1', 'slug-example-2'),
        'operator'  => 'IN'
    )
 )
```

));

This should (imo) return all posts that has a slug that is slug-example-1 or slug-example-2.

I don't even know if `tax_query`/`taxonomy` is the right thing to use.

Comment: Using tax_query, it is expected that the values ​​of the slug field are those of the taxonomy and not those of posts

Comment: i'm looking for a solution...

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Thanks. A last resort would be to filter the posts after the query. I.e. if(in_array($post_slug, $slug_array)) {}

Comment: might work, you have to do some testing

Comment: Looks like there is no real answer. I had to do what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: I had to filter the posts after the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_name__in` argument in conjunction with `get_posts()`, it's available since Version 4.4.
E.g. :

```
$args = [
    'post_name__in' => [ 'slug-1', 'slug-2' ],
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
];
$result = get_posts( $args );
```